# How can I minimize the space between the text and footnote rule?

Tags: adobe-indesign, white-space

I can't seem to figure out how to minimize the space between the bottom of the paragraph and the footnote rule (separator). There seems to be space for at least one more line, which is what I want, so as to avoid a few words at the top of the next page.

Any advice is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It may help if you posted what **application** you are using.

Comment: It's InDesign. My first time using the site. I think I figured out the problem. The continuation of the text had two footnotes associated, so for whatever reason ID couldn't move it all together.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the "extra space" is due to Keep options. You may want to check them:

[image: keep options]

**OR**, check your Footnote options (space before first footnote):

[image: space before first footnote]